# Can I conditionally format a String variable in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, string, format

I'm trying to format a string containing a number as below (with 2 decimal points). However if the string is "", I don't want the format to occur and the output to be blank.

```
var myString: String
cell.myLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", myString)
```

I've tried testing for "", eg

```
if myString == "" {
cell.myLabel.text = myString
}
```

and this:

```
 if myString == "" {
        cell.myLabel.text = ""
       }
```

These both result in `cell.myLabel.text` showing `0.00`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Cells are reused try

```
cell.myLabel.text = myString != "" ? String(format: "%.2f", myString) : ""
```

Comment: hmm. thanks for helping. When I put a value into myString,  reload table  sets myLabel.text to 0.00

Comment: @ICT1901 This is the right answer to the original question, what you are doing now is asking another question within this one which is not how it is supposed to be done. And by including this answer in your latest edit you have made everything very unclear about what is being asked and also why this answer was posted which is not good.

Comment: OK. I'll delete the question and start over.

Comment: @ICT1901 I have rolled it back to the original version

Comment: ok. I can't delete the question, so do you recommend editing it or trying to close it. (I've started that process).

Comment: You should accept this answer and then if you have other issues with your code post a new question